# VUEJS loop comments for post social network with comment.post_id and post.id my database is mysql what's solution please for the loop?

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops, vuejs2

```
    <div
      v-for="(comment, id) in comments
        .map((comment) => {
          if (comment.post_id === poste.id) return comments.length;
        })
        .join('')"
      v-bind:key="id"
      class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-content-center"
    >
      <img
        src="../assets/image/photo3.jpg"
        width="60px"
        height="60px"
        class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
      rounded-circle"
        alt=""
      />
      <div
        class=" d-inline-flex flex-column align-items-start pl-3 largeur100 minHeight bordureRond bodurePost border border-primary backPrimaire"
        min-heigth="60px"
      >
        <p class="stopOpac stopPadMarg text-dark">George Alaman</p>
        <p class="stopOpac text-left stopPadMarg text-secondary">
          {{
            comments
              .map((comment) => {
                if (comment.post_id === poste.id) return comment.comment;
              })
              .join("")
          }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-1 form-group">
      <label class="text-primary" for="commentaire"
        >Laisser un commentaire</label
      >
      <div
        class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-content-center"
      >
        <img
          src="../assets/image/photo3.jpg"
          width="60px"
          height="60px"
          class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
      rounded-circle"
          alt=""
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="commentaire"
          placeholder="Commentaires..."
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what is the solution to have only the number of comments corresponding to the post concerning the loop there are three table sql post, user, and comments in sql they are all linked to each other.
but in front I know how to make the loop I happen to have the number of comments with the map and the comments only link to the posts.
but I can not loop on the main div which will duplicate the comments in the post.

the comments are displayed well only in the posts which have comments the others not nothing so far all is well. but the problem is to duplicate according to their number per post thank you for answering me

you can see there are six messages corresponding to this post and I know how to display the six in text with map () but I can only display the total of the messages of the response it is for the test that I made it. how to display only the six corresponding to this post ?? picture below

[image: here frontend]